# Divide largest value by second largest value

Tags: awk

I am having a file in the following format. Column one has ~20,000 uniq entry and column 2 has ~120,000 different entry and column 3 has count associated with column 2. For a single entry in column 1 there can be multiple entry in column 2. For each unique entry in column 1, I am trying to get ratio of maximum value to second maximum value of column 3.

**F1.txt**

```
S1      S2      C1
A       A1      1
A       AA      10
A       A6      5
A       A0      4
B       BB      12
B       BC      11
B       B1      19
B       B9      4
```

**Expected Output**

```
S1  S2  C1  
B   B1  19  1.58333
A   AA  10  2
```

I can do in steps like bellow. But is there a smart way of doing in in one script?

`awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -k3 -n -r "}' F1.txt | awk '!seen[$1]++' >del1.txt`

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=1; next}FNR==1{print $0;}!a[$2]' del1.txt F1.txt | awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -k3 -n -r"}' | awk '!seen[$1]++' >del2.txt`

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$3; next}FNR==1{print $0"\t";"RT"}FNR>1 a[$1]{print $0"\t"$3/a[$1]}' del2.txt del1.txt`

Comment: With that much data, I'd consider importing it into a SQLite (or other) database if you're going to be doing much analysis on it.

Comment: And what determines the value of the second column that gets displayed? Just the one with the max third column value?

Comment: @Shawn its the maximum value of coulum3 and associated Id of column 2

Comment: Oh, and is the input going to be sorted on the first column?

Comment: @Shawn I did it as I was doing in parts. I need to get largest and second largest value (in column3) for each uniq entry of column1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

NR == 1 { print $1, $2, $3; next }
{ data[$1][$3] = $2 }
END {
  for (key in data) {
    asorti(data[key], s, "@ind_num_desc")
    print key, data[key][s[1]], s[1], s[1] / s[2]
  }
}
```

This^^^ assumes an arbitrary permutation of the lines (and requires `gawk` (which is pretty common) or another implementation with native multi-dimensional “arrays”).

If you can make more assumptions about the input — e.g. that it is always grouped by the first column —, then you can make it more memory-efficient and get rid of multi-dimensional arrays (by *not* delaying the evaluation until `END` and instead calculating it in a per-line block each time the first column’s value changes (and then one last time in `END`).)

To get a different handling of equal numeric values (e.g. to report the “subkey” (column 2) of the first (instead of last) encountered occurrence of a value), you could add `if (!($3 in data[$1])) ...` or the like.

Comment: I like your approach and either I messed up, or you forgot to output the 3rd field in the results before adding the ratio as the new 4th field. I'll double check.

Comment: You’re right, I forgot that field. Edited.

Comment: Works like a champ now, worthy of the UV. Well done pointing out the reliance on GNU awk and that most of the implementations will have it (or mawk) and be virtually compatible.

Comment: You might want to change `s[1] / s[2]` to `(s[2] ? s[1] / s[2] : 0)` or similar so you don't get a divide by zero error if a key only has 1 line or the 2nd-highest value for a key is 0.

Comment: (1/2) That may be way more complex than one ternary operator and it would make the solution quite bloated. A safe division expression (for numerator `n` and denominator `d`) might be something like `d ? n / d : (n ? (n > 0 ? "+inf" + 0 : "-inf" - 0) : "+nan" + 0)` (which is still imperfect, given how AWK treats the `±inf` and `±nan` “literals”). (Admittedly, the `-inf` case cannot occur for this particular data, because `n >= d`, so there is no case with a negative `n` and a zero `d`.) It could be a `function safe_divide(n, d) { ... }` or the like.

Comment: (2/2) Further technicalities are needed to circumvent the fact that in AWK `"0" == 0`, but `0 ? "a" : "b"` yields `b` whereas `"0" ? "a" : "b"` yields `a`. This is [described here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html). So one would need to call `n += 0` and `d += 0` and/or always use (e.g.) `d == 0` rather than just `d` in condition expressions. Again, I’m not convinced that putting all of this into the answer / example would help… The question is somewhat vague when it comes to possible input values.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you find yourself creating a pipeline containing `awk`, there is a very good chance that what you are trying to do can be done in a single call to `awk` much more efficiently.

A non-GNU `awk` approach that presumes all field1 `'A'` records are together and all `'B'` records are together (*as you show in your sample data*) could be:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 { print; next }      ## 1st line, output heading
    $1 != n  {                  ## 1st field changed
        if (n) {                ## if n set, output result of last block
            printf "%s\t%s\n", rec, max / nextmax
        }
        rec = $0                ## initialize vars for next block
        n = $1
        max = $3
        nextmax = 1
        next                    ## skip to next record
    }
    {
        if ($3 > max) {         ## check if 3rd field > max
            rec = $0            ## save record
            nextmax = max       ## update nextmax
            max = $3            ## update max
        }
        else if ($3 > nextmax) {    ## if 3rd field > nextmax
            nextmax = $3            ## update nextmax
        }
    }   ## output final block results
    END { printf "%s\t%s\n", rec, max / nextmax }
' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `file`, you would have:

```
$ awk '
>     FNR==1 { print; next }      ## 1st line, output heading
>     $1 != n  {                  ## 1st field changed
>         if (n) {                ## if n set, output result of last block
>             printf "%s\t%s\n", rec, max / nextmax
>         }
>         rec = $0                ## initialize vars for next block
>         n = $1
>         max = $3
>         nextmax = 1
>         next                    ## skip to next record
>     }
>     {
>         if ($3 > max) {         ## check if 3rd field > max
>             rec = $0            ## save record
>             nextmax = max       ## update nextmax
>             max = $3            ## update max
>         }
>         else if ($3 > nextmax) {    ## if 3rd field > nextmax
>             nextmax = $3            ## update nextmax
>         }
>     }   ## output final block results
>     END { printf "%s\t%s\n", rec, max / nextmax }
> ' file
S1      S2      C1
A       AA      10      2
B       B1      19      1.58333
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and using almost no memory (important since your input file would be huge given your description of it):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 { print; next }
$1 != prev {
    if ( prev != "" ) {
        print prev, val, max, (preMax ? max/preMax : 0)
    }
    prev = $1
    max = ""
}
(max == "") || ($3 > max) {
    val = $2
    preMax = max
    max = $3
}
END { print prev, val, max, (preMax ? max/preMax : 0) }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk F1.txt
S1      S2      C1
A       AA      10      10
B       B1      19      1.58333
```

Comment: Always nice to see a concise way of optimizing the script. The presuming of `'\t'` threw me for a second, but giving the description that looks right. You just have to tweak the sample data in the copy/paste. Removing the `FS=` allows handling both space/tab delimited while preserving the same output format.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I used tab as the separator because the OP is printing literal `"\t"`s in the output in their code, along with it just looking like the data is tab-separated based on the spacing between and left-alignment of the fields. You're right, not setting FS would work either way but then it'd fail if a field could be blank so since I'm pretty certain  the data is tab-separated I figured I'd set it. Easy tweak if I guessed wrong.